# How use suds.client library in python 3.6.2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, suds

I run bellow code in python 2.7 it work good :

```
        from suds.client import client
        client = Client(self.service_address)
        rid = client.service.bpPayRequest(terminalId=self.terminalId,
            userName=self.userName,
            userPassword=self.userPassword,
            orderId=order_id,
            amount=price,
            localDate=local_date,
            localTime=local_time,
            additionalData=additional_data,
            callBackUrl=call_back_address,
            payerId=0)
```

But when i run in python 3.6.2,it does not work.I guess Client is for python 2.How use  suds.client library in python 3.6.2 and run top code in python 3.6.2?

Comment: "It does not work" **always** calls for a "how does it not work? Are there errors? if yes, which errors *in verbatim*?", also, "What have you tried to solve this yourself, so far?".

Comment: The `suds` library doesn't support Python 3. You'll need to install [`suds-py3`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/suds-py3) (a Python 3 compatible fork of `suds`) or switch to an actively-supported client like [Zeep](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/).

Comment: There is also [suds-jurko](https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds), although the maintainer hasn't had time to cut a new release for quite a while.

Answer (score 6):

Try to use

```
$ pip install suds-py3
```

It works for python 3.7.